# Selenium Webdriver browser detection problems

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am writing some automated tests and im having some problems when it comes to browser variations. The Golem framework allows me to enter all browsers i would like to test via the app.config. My tests run beautifully in chrome but have some small issues with finding elements in Firefox and IE. I am wanting to maybe write a if/then statement or switch statement to run a different method when 'X' browser is under test. I cannot seem to find a reliable way to get the current browser version via selenium or the Golem framework.

I have seen examples of `driver.ExecuteJavaScript("return navigator.userAgent;");` but this is not working with IE11. It has no mention of 'MSIE' or 'Microsoft'.

Also maybe i could look at the `[Setup]` method that is looping through the different browsers? Im not sure where to look for that. Im running the tests with ProtoTest TestRunner plugin in VS2013

Comment: I'm a Java guy, but does C# have something like `driver instanceof FirefoxDriver`?

Comment: @SiKing depending your need I guess typeOf or Is will help.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up downloading the source code for the Golem framework and added a new method to return the browser version that the driver is using. Recompiled the dll and replaced it in my existing project. Works like a champ